# Why does my C# TCP/IP Socket Connection to a Print System crash after an hour?

Tags: c#, sockets, client, tcpclient

C# Socket Communication Client to Print System
I need to talk to a Print System via TCP/IP Socket connection.

I used/modified a code snipped from MS to start a TCP/IP Socket connection and send data to the printer. After the connection is closed

```
sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
sender.Close();
```

I'm jumping back into my function to generate a new serial number and open the socket again send the new dynamic data and close the connection.. and so on..
This works for about an hour, then the it crashes (program closes) even within Visual Studio.

In Windows event log the DLL varies from case to case but it looks always something like this.

```
Faulting application name: PrintServerClient.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x8782029c
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.4614.0, time stamp: 0x63995bc5
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000682e80
Faulting process id: 0x73c8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d98d81d24fc9a1
Faulting application path: C:\Users\username\source\repos\PrintServerClient\bin\Debug\net45\PrintServerClient.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: dfec97dc-0bbc-41ea-a9c4-b861460033bf
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

On a virtual test machine (Windows 10 1909) the error also happens after around 1 hour but it is very consistent this error message in event log.

```
Faulting application name: PrintServerClient.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x8bd9b096
Faulting module name: DNSAPI.dll, version: 10.0.18362.267, time stamp: 0x997f6419
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000009104
Faulting process id: 0x1f40
Faulting application start time: 0x01d98d85b37e0c32
Faulting application path: C:\BELLMARK\PrintServerClient.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
Report Id: 9063cd93-208a-4bea-90b6-a635fd439ed2
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Here is a section of my code (the tcp client part), I can also post my whole solution if needed.

```
private void StartClient(byte[] PrintMsg)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[32];
    DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (ButtonStart.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        try
        {
            // Connect to a Remote server
            // Get Host IP Address that is used to establish a connection
            // In this case, we get one IP address of localhost that is IP : 127.0.0.1
            // If a host has multiple addresses, you will get a list of addresses
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[1];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 4500);
            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
            try
            {
                // Connect to Remote EndPoint
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                //Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.
                //byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");
                //byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<STX>#<ETX>");
                byte[] STOP_PRINT = { 02, 17, 03 };


                // Send the data through the socket.
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(STOP_PRINT);
            

                // Receive the response from the remote device.
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                //Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

                // Release the socket.
                try
                {
                    sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    sender.Close();
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    else if (ButtonStart.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
    {
        try
        {
            // Connect to a Remote server
            // Get Host IP Address that is used to establish a connection
            // In this case, we get one IP address of localhost that is IP : 127.0.0.1
            // If a host has multiple addresses, you will get a list of addresses
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[1];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 4500);


            // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
            try
            {
                // Connect to Remote EndPoint
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                //Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Send the data through the socket.
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(PrintMsg);

                // Receive the response from the remote device.
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                //Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                //    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
                

                string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
                string hexString = hex.Replace("-", "");

                string byte1 = hexString.Substring(0, 2);
                string byte2 = hexString.Substring(2, 2);
                string byte3 = hexString.Substring(4, 2);
                string byte4 = hexString.Substring(6, 2);

                try
                {
                    sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    sender.Close();

                    if (byte3 == "06")
                    {
                        InternalPrintCounter++;
                        string ReturnMessage = byte1 + " " + byte2 + " " + byte3 + " " + byte4 + "--> ACK - " + currentDateTime;
                        if (InternalPrintCounter > 5)
                        {
                            InternalPrintCounter = 0;
                            DynamicDataQueueCount(ReturnMessage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SerialNumberGenerator(ReturnMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (byte3 == "15")
                    {

                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried to add a couple of try catch blocks (maybe wrong) but it didn't change the problem.

I appreciate any comments that lead me to the issue and hopefully to a fix.

Comment: Are you doing any PInvoke or unsafe code? Side notes: rather than doing DNS on `localhost` you should just use `IPAddress.Loopback`. And you need to dispose your socket with `using`. And you need to use some kind of message framing as there is no guarantee that what you send is split up the same way when you receive it, TCP is just an unending stream of bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, as you might've guessed, I'm not having a lot of EXP in socket communication. 
What do you mean by dispose your socket with using? 
Would you have an example of message framing? Again I used the plain example form MS, I was unaware of this. Would it help to post the whole solution?

I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: I have made some changes to my code:
added sender.Dispose();
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Loopback;

Comment: There is no _quick response_ on SO. Implying that someone should _quickly_ respond to you will likely lead to you being ignored or your question being closed.

Comment: I didn't mean this comment that he should quickly respond to me, I appreciated only that he responded quickly!!

Comment: And I was honestly surprised that anyone would respond within minutes!! My apologies if that was communicated wrong on my end, I really take every comment and google and educate myself with bits and pieces.

Comment: You shouldn't have any empty `catch` blocks. If you catch an exception it should be written to a log file or displayed. Posts on SO with empty `catch` blocks seem to often be ignored. What kind of project have you created? A Windows Forms Application? A Console Application? A Windows Service?

Comment: I used them after google search and put my break point to it to see if I could catch it manually, not sure if that would work either. But I will add some sort of logging to those catch blocks. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Using an object that implements IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-7.0#using-an-object-that-implements-idisposable)

Comment: I added the error log and this is what showed up:

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4500
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at BellMark_InteliJetTSi_PrintServer.MainWindow.StartClient(Byte[] PrintMsg)

Comment: That message means the system you're trying to connect to isn't accepting your connection. This is normal in TCP socket programming, and you have to handle it gracefully. Frequently you'll see connection attempts in a loop or something.